# Trying to overcome these 6 g++ errors

Tags: c++, g++, gcc-warning

These are the errors/warnings that g++ is putting out and below each is the relevant code. Any help with clearing these errors up or shedding some light on them would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

g++ error:

```
id31.cpp: In function ‘php_var array(int, ...)’:
id31.cpp:462: warning: cannot receive objects of non-POD type ‘class php_var’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
id31.cpp:480: warning: cannot receive objects of non-POD type ‘class php_var’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
```

relevant code:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
php_var array(int key = 0, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, key);
    php_var arr;
    arr.to_array();
    int i = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < key / 2; ++i)
    {
        php_var key2 = va_arg(ap, php_var);
        if(key2 == -1)
        {
            bool found = false;
            for(;;)
            {
                for(i = 0;i < arr.keys.size(); ++i)
                {
                    if(arr.keys[i] == (php_var) i)
                        found = true;
                }
                if(found)
                    ++i;
                else
                    break;
            }
            key2 = i;
        }
        php_var val = va_arg(ap, php_var);
        arr.keys.push_back(key2);
        arr.data.push_back(val);
    };
    va_end(ap);
    return arr;
}
```

gcc error:

```
id31.cpp: In function ‘php_var substr(php_var, php_var, php_var)’:
id31.cpp:511: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator-’ in ‘str.php_var::container.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::length [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]() - pos’
id31.cpp:511: note: candidates are: operator-(size_t, int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:511: note:                 operator-(size_t, double) <built-in>
id31.cpp:511: note:                 operator-(size_t, float) <built-in>
id31.cpp:511: note:                 operator-(size_t, unsigned int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:511: note:                 operator-(size_t, long int) <built-in>
```

Relevant code:

```
php_var substr(php_var str, php_var pos, php_var len)
{
    if(len == 0)
        len = str.container.length() - pos;
    return (php_var) str.container.substr(pos, len);
}
php_var substr(php_var str, long pos, long len)
{
    if(len == 0)
        len = str.container.length() - pos;
    return (php_var) str.container.substr(pos, len);
}
```

gcc error:

```
id31.cpp:592: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator-’ in ‘_length - strlen(php_var)()’
id31.cpp:592: note: candidates are: operator-(const char*, const char*) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(const char*, int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(const char*, int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(const char*, int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(int, int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(int, double) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(int, float) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(int, unsigned int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(int, long int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(double, int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(double, double) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(double, float) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(double, unsigned int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(double, long int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(float, int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(float, double) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(float, float) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(float, unsigned int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(float, long int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(unsigned int, int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(unsigned int, double) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(unsigned int, float) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(unsigned int, unsigned int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(unsigned int, long int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(long int, int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(long int, double) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(long int, float) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(long int, unsigned int) <built-in>
id31.cpp:592: note:                 operator-(long int, long int) <built-in>
```

relevant code:

```
php_var _recruit = _length - (php_var)strlen(_flag);
if (_recruit < (php_var)1)
{
    return _flag;

_end_18:
    return (php_var)sprintf((string)(const char*)(php_var)"%0" + (string)(const char*)_length + (string)(const char*)(php_var)"d", _flag);

}
```

gcc error:

```
id31.cpp:598: error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)’
```

relevant code:

```
if (_recruit < (php_var)1)
{
    return _flag;

_end_18:
    return (php_var)sprintf((string)(const char*)(php_var)"%0" + (string)(const char*)_length + (string)(const char*)(php_var)"d", _flag);

}
```

Comment: Could you please split these into separate questions?  Many of the issues seem unrelated.

Comment: Doesn't effect the answer at all, but you should know that names that start with an underscore are reserved, you shouldn't use them in your code.

Comment: @Evan: this is false, names that start with `_[A-Z]` or contains `__` (a double underscore) are reserved, others are fine.

Comment: @Matthieu: **17.4.3.2.1**: `Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.`

Comment: @Evan: ah, but that's the global namespace here. Other scopes are fine, and in particular within a function, class, etc... I don't know how labels are treated wrt to scopes though :/

Comment: @Matthieu: while you are right about it being for global namespace, I see no indication of where `_flag`, `_length`, `_recruit`, etc are defined. For we know they may be globals.

Comment: @Evan: I will admit I could not bring myself to read the code, I tried... but my eyes bled during the first chunk and then I skimmed over. Would not surprise me if they were globals -_-

Comment: @Evan, ok, ok... sorry if the code offends you. I am about 3 weeks into learning c++. I am a PHP programmer. This code was derived from a  tool call bianryPHP, which compiles PHP code to c++ (which I am trying to do in order to benefit from the speed c++ provides). So this was the .cpp file that was dumped. I am now trying to clean it up so that it can compile.

Comment: @cube: No offense :-) I was not trying to attack you or your code. The fact that this is machine generated explains a lot of the craziness of the code actually! I imagine your tool targeted an older less conformant compiler. So you may have some serious work cut out for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're passing a `php_var` object as parameter for variadic function `php_var array(int key = 0, ...)`. This is not allowed. Only POD objects can be passed as variadic parameters.
2. and 3. There's no `operator-` defined between an `int` (or the type of `_length`, don't know what type it is) and a `php_var`.
3. `sprintf` takes, as first argument, a `char*`, while you're passing a `std::string` to it. Use `std::string::c_str()` to convert your string to a `const char*`

Answer (score 2):

The first error is simple, you just can't pass objects of type `php_var` as variadic parameters (parameters to functions which specific `...` are the parameters).

As for the other errors, hard to say without seeing the definition of `php_var` itself.

What the heck are you intending when you write: `(string)(const char*)(php_var)"%0"` ?!

you take a string then cast it to some unknown type, then cast it **back** to a `const char*` (which it was to begin with), then force it to be a `std::string` (which can't be passed to `printf`)... **why?**

The last two snippets **look** like you are trying to let a parameter specify the length attribute of a `printf`, if you look at the man page for it, you'll see the proper way is to just do this: `printf("%*d", width, num);`. Simply placing a `*` where the "width" option is expected tells `printf` to take it from another passed parameter.

Finally, all of that casting you are doing is a sign of really bad code, when you do things correctly, casting should be a very infrequent occurrence.

Comment: I know, I should be ashamed of myself for even attempting to try this, but nonetheless, this is a .cpp that was generated by the PHP to c++ converter called binaryPHP, found on sourceforge. I am trying to clean it up while learning c++, as I am a PHP programmer. Maybe I am in over my head with this code which appears to be poorly converted.

Answer (score 2):

POD => [Plain old data](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) : varargs have been created for the C language, they can only be used with superstructure that not contain constructor/destructor.